# How I can migrate the blob data type in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have below table in DB2:
CREATE TABLE Test_table (Test_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, Test_CONTENT BLOB(104857600) NOT NULL);
In Test_CONTENT field i have many Binary files which i want to insert in new DB2 table which is on another server.
How I can do this migration with the help of Pentaho ?
i.e. 
My new table having same structure as above only it will be on different server.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, i suggest you should first read how to ask a good question here; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Make two empty database and use the same name which you have used in your remote server then copied the all data in it.